Start up failing post upgrading to Spring Boot 2.7.18
I am upgrading Spring Boot from 2.4.3 to 2.7.18. My POM looks as below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.seqnc</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-gateway-server</name>
    <description>API Gateway</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>api-gateway</finalName>
    </build>

</project>

I am getting below error on startup
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/datta/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/datta/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.13.3/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.13.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/datta/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.12/logback-classic-1.2.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/datta/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.17.2/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.BootstrapRegistryInitializer : org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.TextEncryptorConfigBootstrapper
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:425)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:266)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1289)
    at com.seqnc.ApiGatewayServerApplication.main(ApiGatewayServerApplication.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/Bootstrapper
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:443)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.Bootstrapper
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 21 more

I am using Java 17. It looks like some JAR is referring to org/springframework/boot/Bootstrapper which is a deprecated class and removed from version 2.6. So what would be the correct spring-clod-dependencies version for 2.7.18? I am using 2021.0.9 currently

Spring Cloud 2021.0.9 specifies Spring Boot 2.6.15, while Spring Cloud 2022.0.5 specifies Spring Boot 3.0.13 (and 2023.0.3 specifies Spring Boot 3.2.7), so take your pick.

@MarkRotteveel I am already using correct version which is 2021.0.9

Yes, but with Spring Boot 2.7. Either pick 2021.0.9 and use Spring Boot 2.6.x, or use 2022.05, and use Spring Boot 3.0.x, or use 2023.0.3 and use Spring Boot 3.2.x (BTW, are you sure Spring Cloud is the source of this issue)?

I tried "pick 2021.0.9 and use Spring Boot 2.6.15". But problem still persists. I am not quite sure if its because of spring-cloud. But I am not using Bootstrapper class in my code. So some jar is using it don't know which one

"some jar is using it" --> mvn dependency:tree might help

Issue got resolved after adding below dependency to my pom
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>

